# how to validate the selected option to only one time can be used, not double, can it?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm a beginner in cakephp, help me please. I have stuck when I think to validate input type selected in form cakephp, the data is detail, so many rows there, first line.

```
<select id="AirWayBillDetail0ItemId" name="data[AirWayBillDetail][0][item_id]">
<option value="">-- Select an Item --</option>
<option value="9">Handphone</option>
<option value="10">Accecoris</option>
<option value="11">Alat Tulis Kantor</option>
<option value="12">Voucher Fisik</option>
</select>
```

I want the option, just one time can be used.

Example:
Add first line, I select handphone, 
so, the second line, cannot used that option. Is there any way to clear my trouble?

[image]

Can I validate in Model or in View or Controller? With javascript or jquery?

Comment: Never, *ever*, rely on validation via JavaScript, you should always have validation performed server-side even if you supplement it with JavaScript validation. Your validation rules ideally want to be in the model. Could you clarify what you mean by "add first line, i select handphone, so, the second line, cannot used that option"? Do you mean that your form shows multiple selects for `item_id`?

Comment: Please explain more  :--->   example, add first line, i select handphone, so, the second line, cannot used that option,

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/rqjtG.png look at this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to check this in the model or controller layers. Never rely on JavaScript for validation as this can lead to vulnerabilities in your app (JavaScript can easily be disabled). You should always validate on the server-side and can supplement this with client-side validation if you want some additional inline validation.

You want to add a check that there are no duplicate `item_id` in your submitted data. So you could do something like the following in your controller:-

```
$itemIds = Hash::extract($this->request->data, 'AirWayBillDetail.{n}.item_id');
if (count($itemIds) !== count(array_unique($itemIds))) {
    // Invalid item_ids
}
```

You'd then need to handle how you'd want the error messages showing and ensure it doesn't proceed to save. If you want to do this in the model you need to look at using the `beforeSave()` callback to check `$this->data` before saving and return `false` if duplicated are identified.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i have another trouble that the empty data, when i select default or -- select an Item -- (look at the picture number 4 and 5) there is no description, but when i count, the data is also counted, how to fix it ?

Comment: the data array print : 

Array
(
    [0] => 9
    [1] => 10
    [2] => 11
    [3] => 
    [4] =>
)

Comment: @OnesinusSaut not sure I follow. If you have a new question you should post it as a new one.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement this with jQuery.
Please refer this fiddle `http://jsfiddle.net/sqy1n6n3/1/`

```
$('select').on('change', function() {

    $('select').find('option').prop('disabled', false);

    $('select').each(function() {
       $('select').not(this).find('option[value="' + this.value + '"]').prop('disabled', true); 
    });

});
```

Comment: Please don't rely on client-side validation, these leaves the app vulnerable!